# Converting a string into a usable name such as interface, type or properties in C#

Tags: c#, string, reflection, interface

I am having a hard time in figuring out how to convert strings (generally speaking) into actual code.

The first thing I have tried (and succeeded) was to convert a string containing a "Property name" into an actual useful property and then modify the property value.

For those interested, here is how I came up with that. ie. Making the string "PropertyName" an actual property:

```
typeof(IModule).GetProperty("PropertyName").SetValue(SomeModule, true, null);
```

Now, the second thing was to figure out how to do the same thing with "IModule"  (I so far failed miserably in finding a way to do this).

I have tried Type.GetType("IModule"), but it returns a null. I also tried providing the path to the actual dll (assembly), which also did not work. Reason for it not to work might be something to do with Interops.

In order to summarize, how can I do the following thing out of strings:

```
"IModule" SomeModule = ("Imodule").DoSomething;
```

Finally, I would like to do the same thing with "SomeModule".

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do? .NET does allow this sort of reflection to a great degree, but it's never convenient or comfortable. Are you trying to make your own dependency injection container or plugin configuration system? Those already exist and are probably more convenient than roll-your-own.

Comment: The grand plan is to have a couple of lists containing strings with interfaces and properties and to have then a generic loop to cycle through the lot and set properties as needed. 
There are lots of modules, so I don't want to be typing all by hand and this would prevent from duplicating a lot of code.

Comment: If you know the types (interfaces/classes) beforehand, it's better to use static typing as much as possible. For example `var interfaces = new List<Type> { typeof(IMyInterface), typeof(IAnotherInterface), ... `. Otherwise you'll have to use `Assembly.GetType(string)`, which requires getting a reference to the assembly that contains each type that you want to use.

Comment: Bypassing the static type checking like this means the compiler will gladly compile your code even if you made a mistake when typing one of those strings. Things that are actually coding errors will not show up until you execute the program and it tries to access a type or property that doesn't exist, which will cause an exception to be thrown. 
To address the problem of code duplication, I would instead use tools to generate parts of the source code, so that these errors lead to compile errors. There might be other, even better ways to solve the problem for your particular case.

Comment: typeof(IMyInterface) is not an option as IMyInterface must be a string.
I did not manage to get Assembly.GetType(string) to work. Always returns null.

I understand that the bypass is not ideal, but would be ideal to me :-) I will eventually, implement each part individually without strings, but it will imply significantly more work. So as a first step I would like to do it that way.